# PHP Need help with MYSQL DB and dates

Tags: php, mysql, database, date

I have two fields in the DB stating the start-time and end-time, and another field that may or may be not set that is called 'date'.

Upon SELECT, I need to know if I am in or out of the time range, and if the date is set if I am in the time range only if the date is today.

What is the best way to do that in PHP ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My original answer was not answering your question at all I realised. Hopefully this will.

```
$query = "SELECT IF(".date('H-m-s')." BETWEEN start-time AND end-time, 
'inRange', 'notInRange') WHERE `date` == CURRENT_DATE OR `date` IS NULL";
```

If date('H-m-s') from PHP is in the range it will return the string "inRange" otherwise it will return the string "notInRange" and will match it on the records in your db where date is either NULL, or the current date.

You could also make the SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT IF(TIME(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN start-time AND end-time, 'inRange',
'notInRange') WHERE myDate == CURRENT_DATE OR myDate IS NULL;
```

Comment: I am not too familiar with the syntax, looks like an if is executed for each row, returning the result 'inRange', 'notInRange' accordingly. Where is the result being put ? Thanks!

Comment: It will match on the records where the field `myDate` - which I reckon you will call `date` - is either set to CURRENT_DATE (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date) or is NULL, and execute the IF-condition for these, and return a 'inRange' or 'noInRange' for each of the matched records. If you need more data than just 'inRange'/'noInRange' to identify the records when processing the result you could just add it normally, e.g. `select col1, col2 if()...`. If you do it in PHP using mysql_query/mysqli_query you will get the response as an object.

Answer (score 2):

> Upon SELECT, I need to know if I am in or out of the time range

```
SELECT (NOW() BETWEEN date_min AND date_max) is_happening_now
  FROM your_table
```

is_happening_now contains a boolean containing true if NOW() is between date_min and date_max. Obviously, that would create a separate column that you might not need, you can put the condition in the WHERE clause if necessary.

> if the date is set if I am in the time range only if the date is today.

I didn't really understand this part, but you can extract the date from a DATETIME with the DATE function (for example : `current_date = DATE(some_date)`